# 'UpdateView' object has no attribute 'object'

Tags: python, django, django-views

So I've been trying to add a cancel button to my UpdateView that I've been using. Here's my code for it:

views.py:

```
class CountryEditView(generic.edit.UpdateView):
    model = Country
    fields = ['name']
    template_name_suffix = '_edit'  

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if "cancel" in request.POST:
            url = self.object.get_absolute_url()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
        else:
            return super(CountryEditView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
# etc....
```

models.py:

```
class Country(AutoUpdateModel): #A subclass of models.Model
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('appName:country_info', args=(self.id,))
    #etc...
```

country_edit.html:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
    <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel" />
</form>
```

However I've been getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\username\Envs\projName\appName\views.py", line 38, in post

    url = self.object.get_success_url()
AttributeError: 'CountryEditView' object has no attribute 'object'
```

This doesn't make sense to me, since the [documentation page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView.object) says `When using UpdateView you have access to self.object, which is the object being updated.` Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do, but you overrode `post()`, which is where `object` is assigned. So you need to call the method to get it directly yourself:

```
class CountryEditView(generic.edit.UpdateView):
    model = Country
    fields = ['name']
    template_name_suffix = '_edit'  

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if "cancel" in request.POST:
            object = self.get_object()
            url = object.get_absolute_url()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
        else:
            return super(CountryEditView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

You should check out [CCBV](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.10/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/) - you can see what each method is doing very easily.

Side notes:

1) You can just pass in an object to [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) if it has `get_absolute_url` defined:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if "cancel" in request.POST:
        object = self.get_object()
        return redirect(object)
```

Comment: why define `post` twice?